# Enterprise Architect 12.1 how to enable scripting?

Tags: scripting, enterprise-architect

New to using Enterprise Architect 12.1 so please excuse my ignorance - the documentation isn't very hepful.  How dos one enable the scripting facility?  It seems as though I should be able to select the scripting window from the Project menu item but that option doesn't appear.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Scripting is only available in Corporate edition or higher. Do you have the professional edition by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

The menu option in v12.1 is actually located under **Tools | Scripting**

If the option is not there that is usually because of one of the reasons below:

### Your license doesn't include scripting

Scripting is only available in the editions **Corporate** or higher. If you have a Professional license then you won't be able to use scripting.

More information about the different editions of Enterprise Architect can be found here: https://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html

### The menu option is hidden

This was a very common problem right after version 12 came out introducing different menu sets for different profiles.
To make sure you have all the menu options available go to **View | Perspectives | Menu Sets** and make sure to select the **Complete** menu set.
[image]

Comment: Sadly, neither of the possible causes you have identified is the case.  I believe the I have the Ultimate edition (that's what the licence says) and I've checked the menu set.  Is it possible that I have a demonstration version of the software?

Comment: The evaluation version includes scripting I thought.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned the wrong menu option in your question. I've updated the answer with the correct menu location.

Comment: Thanks to all of you - it seems that the answer is simply that the Workspaces and Commands window does not show the current state as one might expect, so to expose all the menu commands it is important to click the OK pad.

Comment: That's a tricky one. So it was a hidden menu option after all.